# What is this overlapped widget name?

Tags: flutter

[image]

what is this overlap widget ? or is this some kind of effect ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function on **button click:**

```html
void _settingModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return Container(
        child: new Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.music_note),
                title: new Text('Music'),
                onTap: () => {}
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.videocam),
              title: new Text('Video'),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html), You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) package to create powerful modal bottom sheets.